# import pdf with mpdf shows imports only a layer of the pdf

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I'm trying to import a pdf by using the import functionality of mpdf.

```
        $this->mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();
        $this->mpdf->setSourceFile("paybackform/Attest-psychotherapie_tcm47-25501.pdf");
        $tplId = $this->mpdf->importPage(1);
        $this->mpdf->addPage();
        $this->mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId);

        $this->mpdf->output();
```

I already tried a lot of different input PDF's but mpdf never outputs the same output pdf as the one i put in. Depending on which input pdf i use, the graphics are stripped, or large parts of the text are removed. In the best case I see only a part of the text. For some input PDF's i only get a grey background in the output pdf with no text at all.

I tried upgrading mpdf to the latest version, with no result. I have tried importPage() & ImportPage(), with addPage(), without addPage(). It seems like I'm stuck. I couldn't find a question on SO that resembles my question.

Does anyone have a clue about what could be the problem here?

Regards

Lieven

Comment: mPDF comes with certain [limitations](https://mpdf.github.io/about-mpdf/limitations.html) and [known issues](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/known-issues.html). You may have run into some. To debug this, you could incrementally build the PDF and see what the import gives you at each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that it's actually the minifier of my api (that minifies the output of my api) was the cause for this problem! Disabling this minifier before downloading a PDF solves it.

So it has nothing to do with mpdf

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Please share your input PDF and output which shows the wrong behavior.

Comment: I made an animated gif. First I demonstrate correct generation of pdf when write to file. Then I remove the arguments of the output function and you see a grey background instead of the template file.

I made an animated gif. First I demonstrate correct generation of pdf when write to file. Then I remove the arguments of the output function and you see a grey background instead of the template file.

[demo of problem][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCGJF.gif

Comment: Still not enough information to analyze this. Can it be that you call `Output()` more than once? How is the final PDF send to the client at all? Please share both output PDFs (correct and faulty one).

Comment: Hi, you were right @janSlabon. This wasn't the solution at all. I kept on getting the same problem when I wanted to download the pdf via my API. After debugging for a while I found out that the function that minifies the responses of my API was the cause for this problem. So it has nothing to do with mpdf